# zsh: how do I get ctrl-p and ctrl-n keys to perform history-search-backward/forward like in bash?

Tags: zsh

In zsh, I can search my history based on what has been typed on the command line so far with:

```
    bindkey "\e[A" history-search-backward
    bindkey "\e[B" history-search-forward
```

So if I type in:

`ln -s som`

and hit the up arrow, it will show me the most recent command that begins with `ln -s som`.

In bash, I used the ctrl-p and ctrl-n to do the same thing to make it more convenient to type:

```
    bindkey "\C-p" history-search-backward
    bindkey "\C-n" history-search-forward
```

However, when I try binding C-p and C-n to the history search in zsh, the results are based on the first **word** in the command. So if I type in:

`ln -s som`

and then hit C-p, it will show all previous results that start with `ln` instead of `ln -s som`

Anybody know how I can get C-n and C-p to behave like bash in zsh?

**UPDATE:** I've tried various iterations of key sequence like:

```
bindkey "^p" ...
bindkey "^P" ...
bindkey "^P" ... (using ^V then ^P) to generate the "^P" character
bindkey "C-p" ...
bindkey "Ctrl-p" ...
```

But none of these make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the widget you need to get the behavior I describe is `history-beginning-search-backward`

So this works now:

```
   bindkey '^P' history-beginning-search-backward
   bindkey '^N' history-beginning-search-forward
```